# Convert UVmap attribute to UVmaps using geometry nodes

Tags: uv, geometry-nodes

What I want is to make a mesh ready to be exported with its UVs after applying the geometry nodes modifier, it can be done manually (converting UVmap attribute to UVmaps), but is there any way to do it automatically using the geometry nodes.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

if you look next to the menu your attribute is in there are `+` and `-` buttons; below that there is a down arrow `v`, if you click that dropdown there is an option to convert it to a *uv map*.

Comment: Not the OP but it worked for me, thanks!!