# Convert attribute mode "UVMap" is missing from the dropdown

Tags: uv, geometry-nodes

I'm using blender 3.5.1, I've seen other users mention and screenshot this option, but I cant find it. Apparently added in 3.1 https://devtalk.blender.org/t/convert-face-corner-attribute-to-uv-map/22132/7

[image]

you can also see it mentioned here: [Convert UVmap attribute to UVmaps using geometry nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/290650/convert-uvmap-attribute-to-uvmaps-using-geometry-nodes?rq=1)

The only conversion modes available to me are generic and vertex group:

[image]

I do see that the conversion mode is present in blender 3.1, so has it been moved or removed in 3.5?

Comment: UVMap is the *name* of an attribute, which is a Generic mode in the Faceee Corner domain, of type 2D-vector.  There is no "UVMap" mode -- again it is an attribute's *name*.  You'll see that if your double click on UVMap, (F2), you can change its name.

Comment: There definitely was a conversion mode called UV map in 3.1 as you can see here, I am not confusing it with the name of the attribute, you can see I have no attribute named UVMap here:  https://imgur.com/a/ibkNjlM

This mode isn't present in 3.5: https://imgur.com/a/ieHv7zn